# Mysql query performing very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have one table with approx 20M records, and I am going to simple compute on some of the fields of that table. But it is taking to much time to fetch data. I am considering all records that's why no index comes in a picture. 
Let me explain :

```
Table : UserLoginDet
        ------------ 
LoginID    INT
UserID     INT
Date       DATETIME
SpentTime  INT
```

Now I want total for my dashboard like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) NoOfLogins, DISTINCT(UserID) NoOfUsers, SUM(SpentTime) UsedTime;
```

This query taking 5-6 seconds to execute. Is it ok or not. I think it is very slow for just 20M records. What should I have to do?

EDITED : 
My explain report :

```
id Select_type  table        type  possible_key  key      key_len  ref   rows    Extra
-- -----------  -----        ----  ------------  -------  -------  ---   ------  ------ 
1  PRIMARY  UserLoginDet     range PRIMARY      PRIMARY  3              797143  Using where
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that 20 thousand or 20 million?  Please fix typo...

Comment: @PinnyM, It is million

Comment: The time seems normal for a full table scan.

Comment: Hi @Vatev, Is it ok? I read somewhere that mysql perform compute operation very fast of millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) NoOfLogins, DISTINCT(UserID) NoOfUsers, SUM(SpentTime) UsedTime;` to see a detailed report of the index usage.

Comment: Hi @Paolo-casciello, I have checked using explain, and this query used PRIMARY KEY to search. and showing 'Using where' in 'Extra'. Is it ok?

Comment: @ManishSapkal can you add the output of explain to your original post?

Comment: Hi @Paolo-casciello, I have added output of explain in to my post

Comment: @ManishSapkal yeah it uses the primary key. So it's an ideal scenario. And yes, the time seems normal. Depends also on the system (os, cpu, memory, status of the caches, disk)